# Calculate total sales from selected year till current date in spotfire

Tags: sql, spotfire

I have a filter column that contains "year". Now I want to calculate total sales from selected year till current date.
I tried below query but it didn't work

```
Sum(case WHEN Year([Date column])=Year(DateTimeNow()) THEN [Total_Sales] END)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use your expression you are trying to sum only when Year of your date column match current Year.

If I understand your question you could try this :

```
Sum(If(Year([Date column])<=Year(DateTimeNow()),[Total_Sales]))
```

Regards